# Ansible: how to handle dots while using search or match functions

Tags: regex, ansible

Here are the two scenarios and variable prefix will just hold another string.

1)This works:

```
 when: ansible_hostname | search("{{ prefix }}-test-.*")
```

2)This doesn't work probably because of dots in the search string.

```
 when: ansible_hostname | search("{{ prefix }}-test-.*.tin.com)
```

I even tried escaping dots without any success.

```
when: ansible_hostname | search("{{ prefix }}-test-.*\.tin\.com)
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of hostnames you are dealing with?

Comment: all 3 regexs are legit and should match something like `hst-test-suffix.domain.tin.com`. Example of ansible_hostname is needed.

Comment: host example = bgl1-1-tin-more-001.company.com

Comment: and I'm on ansible 1.5.4 on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: `bgl1-1-tin-more-001.company.com` can not match `{{ prefix }}-test-.*.tin.com`

Comment: my bad... gave a wrong/tweaked host name. bgl1-1-tin-test-001.tin.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I understand that `ansible_hostname` will give you only part of fqdn and hence since my regex was trying to look for fqdn with `.tin.com` it was not matching. For time being I'll be using `groups['name']` to iterate over my hosts and get the fqdn.
Note: Ansible has `ansible_fqdn` to give the complete host name however that works fine only if DNS is configured.